# Create Table Query Error

Tags: c#, database, oracle

```
command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE daily_prostock (product_id varchar2(30),daily_prounit number(30) not null,day varchar2(30),FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product_description (product_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION  )";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This command is not working . please help

Comment: "not working" isn't that specific, see [ask]

Comment: Please provide more information.  What version of Oracle.  What isn't working?  Is there an error?  Please post a more complete example.

Comment: I love these guessing games...

Answer (score 3):

A constraint needs to be explicitly specified with `constraint < constraint_name >` as below.

I question slightly the need to create a table in c# if you're doing it more than once. Why isn't it already in the database?

`on delete no action` is the [default](http://www.dba-oracle.com/bk_on_delete_restrict_on_delete_no_action_tips.htm) and doesn't actually need to be specified.

```
CREATE TABLE daily_prostock (
     product_id varchar2(30)
   , daily_prounit number(30) not null
   , day varchar2(30)
   , constraint daily_prostock_fk
        FOREIGN KEY (product_id) 
       REFERENCES product_description (product_id) )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE daily_prostock (
product_id varchar2(30),
daily_prounit number(30) not null,
day varchar2(30),
constraint fkproduct 
FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product_description (product_id) )
```

The on delete no action has been removed as it will cause error, as it's the default Cascade in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

As Raphaël Althaus pointed out, there is a NO ACTION option, which is actually the default, so omitting ON DELETE from the table definition will actuate this behavior. <del>There is no "ON DELETE NO ACTION" in Oracle. The options for ON DELETE are SET NULL or 
CASCADE</del>:

```
CREATE TABLE daily_prostock (
  product_id varchar2(30),
  daily_prounit number(30) not null,
  day varchar2(30),
  FOREIGN KEY (product_id) 
  REFERENCES product_description (product_id) 
)
```

Comment: Wrong. It exists (>9i), but can't be used in a CREATE TABLE statement.
http://www.dba-oracle.com/bk_on_delete_restrict_on_delete_no_action_tips.htm

Comment: Thanks. I will amend the answer.